# Javascript 'x' is not defined error

Tags: javascript, undefined

The following code results in 'favlist is not defined'. Despite trying to define favlist in various ways I then get 'favlist.style is undefined' and other errors. I am sure this is simple enough but I am obviously simpler still.....

```
function checkCookie() {
    favs=getCookie('favs');
    if (favs=="on"){
        favlist.style.display="inline"; 
    } else {
        favlist.style.display="none";   
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: "Despite trying to define favlist in various ways"... where?

Comment: Where did you define favlist?

Comment: Sorry only just seen these comments. favlist is a div - solved (see below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually define `favlist`, as the error message suggests. Assuming `favlist` is meant to be a reference to an element in the DOM, the easiest way to do that would be to use `getElementById` (assuming your element has an `id`):

```
var favlist = document.getElementById("myFavlistElement");
```

Bear in mind that if you need to use `favlist` outside of the `checkCookie` function, you will need to define `favlist` outside of that function too, or it won't be in scope.

Comment: It was not the js causing the problem. The div with an id of 'favlist' was not always present in the html source.

Comment: Thanks for your reply though - it put me on track!